# Passar dados de um form para um listview de outro form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, textbox

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em c# onde preciso em um form buscar o número da nota e ao clicar em adicionar, ele passe as informações para o form principal no listview. Alguém pode me ajudar a como desenvolver isso? Obrigada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu form para adicionar o numero da nota
        public partial class FrmAddRemessa : Form
    {
        public int iRetorno = 0;

```
    public FrmAddRemessa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Txt_CodigoRemessa_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_CodigoRemessa.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;

        var oNota = new RemessaNG().BuscarNota(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoRemessa.Text.Trim()));



        txt_CodigoCliente.Text = Convert.ToInt32(oNota.ClienteID).ToString();
        txt_NotaID.Text = Convert.ToInt32(oNota.NotaID).ToString();


        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_CodigoCliente, new EventArgs());
        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_NotaID, new EventArgs());

    }

    private void Txt_CodigoRemessa_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Txt_CodigoRemessa_Validating(txt_CodigoRemessa, new CancelEventArgs());
        }
    }


    private void Txt_CodigoCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Verifica se está vazio
        if (txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;

        var oCliente = new RemessaNG().BuscarCliente(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim()));

        txt_NomeCliente.Text = oCliente.Nome;

        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_CodigoCliente, new EventArgs());
        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_CodigoRemessa, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void Bt_Adicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_NotaID.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;

            iRetorno = Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoRemessa.Text.Trim());

    }
```

E esse é meu botão do adicionar no form
`        private void Bt_AdicionarNota_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        var frmAddRemessa = new FrmAddRemessa();
        frmAddRemessa.ShowDialog();
        var iRetorno = frmAddRemessa.iRetorno;
        //iRetorno = 0
        if (iRetorno < 1)
            return;




    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Rayane, vc precisa ter acesso ao `Form1` dentro do `Form2`. Você pode fazer isso passando o objeto do `Form1` por referência ao criar o `Form2`, por exemplo.

No `Form1`, vc cria o `Form2` deste modo:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
```

Obs: o `this` é o próprio objeto do `Form1` sendo passado por referência.

No `Form2`, vc armazena o `Form1`, passado por referência no método construtor, em uma variável privada, por exemplo `meuForm1`:

```
private Form1 meuForm1;

public Form2(Form1 frm1) {
    InitializeComponent();
    meuForm1 = frm1;
}
```

Assim, o botão dentro do `Form2` pode chamar o objeto `meuForm1` e alterar o `ListView` dele, por exemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    meuForm1.listView1.Items.Add("");
}
```

Não se esqueça de mudar a visibilidade (Propriedade Modifiers) do `ListView` do `Form1` para `public`, para você ter acesso a ele a partir de outros objetos!

Comment: Wilson, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigada pela sua ajuda

Comment: @RayanneBorges, se ajudou a resolver o problema, marque a resposta como solução para a pergunta! ;)